# Mapping two models to use example.com/<name>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `user` model and a `project` model in my app. I want both of these to have their `show/edit` actions on `http://example.com/<username or project name>` and `http://example.com/<username or project name>/edit`

If it were only one model, I could have added a `match '/:username'` condition with a low priority in my routes. How would I go about doing this with multiple models?

Comment: How will you handle when a user is named like a project, or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bad idea -- I would not recommend you do this. There is probably a better way to accomplish your needs -- what's wrong with `example.com/users/123/`

However, if you must do it, you could probably create a third controller, which, I'll call a shortcut controller.

First you'd need to route to the shortcut controller so the `:/name` variable is passing to it for show and edit. See ideas for the routing in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages).

Then in your shortcut controller actions you'd need to have a priority order (in case a user and project have the same name), where you first check for a username matching the given name and show/edit that or else look for a project and then show an error 404.

It would look something like:

```
def show
  if @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    render 'users/show'
  elsif @project = Project.find_by_name(params[:name])
    render 'projects/show'
  else
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Error message"
  end
end
```

Anyway, that could probably be made to work, but again I'm not sure it's a good idea, and I suspect there are a lot of kinks in that idea you'll have to work out. Good luck!